# svn annotate fails in intellij, but works on cmd line

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

When I try to run `svn blame` via IntelliJ's `VCS -> Subversion -> Annotate` option, I get back the following error:

```
Error: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
```

All other svn operations (e.g. check out, update, diff, etc.) I use work fine in IntelliJ, and `svn blame` on the same file returns instantly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by not allowing incoming connections on MacOS. I purged IntelliJ from the prohibited list, rebooted, and this time allowed incoming network connections, and now it works.